# Why i am not able to get the data in custom List view after coming back from next activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-listview, android-2.2-froyo

In My Application there are three screen.
1. Main Menu
2. Custom ListView Activity
3. Detail page Activity

Now, I have implemented the adapter and the custom ListView to the ListView Activity.
I am going to add some data to the ListView Activity. But that data should be selected from the detail page Activity.

So After selecting the data from the detail Page if i come back to ListView activity then the data is not reflacted. But if i finish that ListView Activity and come again to ListView Activity from the Main Menu. Thus i got the selected value.

So whats wrong ? Why i am not able to get the effect instantly if i change the data from the detail page.

I think Whenever i come back to ListViewActivity, i have to refresh all data. But i dont know how.
So will you please help me for that ?

Thanks.

Comment: How you set the data for listview activity? Data taken from db or some other way??

Comment: Data taken from static variable.

Comment: thn start your list activity newly by passing value from detailaPage activity to customlistactivity

Comment: @deepa: i have done like it. And it solve my Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refresh your `ListView` call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `Adapter`.

Comment: I have use it but still i am not able to get the value. that i have changed from the detail page. But after while i come back from the main menu then i got that data. SO what should i have to do it ? Is it possible to get start listActivity again while come back from the Detali Page.

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose what the problem is when you haven't posted any code.

Comment: Yes You are right. But i just want it is to restart that activity while i come back to that activity.

Answer (score 1):

1. when you comming back to your list view, are you associating a new adapter / refreshing the data in the list? as the Listview that you see is from the stack. with previous data.
2. Alternatively, while going to details page you can call finish for list, so that when you relaunch the list you get a fresher list.

   ```
   public void actionPerformed(View v){
     startActivityForResult(getIntent(),0);
   }
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(data.getExtras()));
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }
   ```

Comment: ok Let me try your second one idea. And with your first one idea, i am not associating or refreshing the data in the list. So how to do it.

Comment: Finishimg the ListActivity and start it again from the detail Activity is not right idea for my app. So whats other possibility to get the data ?

Comment: then you have to do the 1st one only.
simply associate a new adapter in onStart to your listview.
it should solve your issue.
Alternatively you can also start your new activity using startActivityFOrResult and in onActivityResult associate a new adapter to your list view.

Comment: Any sample code to do for using startActivityForResult ?? for such type of problem ?